# How do you inject a Symfony repository into a custom user provider?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have successfully injected repositories into services before, but can't get injection to work in a custom user provider. It seems like the __construct() method is never getting called, so the repository is never made available. The way you are supposed to make a user provider is to implement the interface UserProviderInterface, but the UserProvider class you create doesn't extend another class that would have a constructor. When I try to access the repository using $this->personRepository->findStatusByUsername($username), I get the error:

> Using $this when not in object context

One reason I think the constructor is never getting called is that it has two assignments to $this, but I'm not getting an error message about them.

I need the Person repository to be injected so that I can check whether or not the person trying to authenticate is already approved in the app (status in the Person table = approved.)

My services.yml file has these settings:

```
parameters:
  ginsberg_transportation.user.class: Ginsberg\TransportationBundle\Services\User
  user_provider.class: Ginsberg\TransportationBundle\Security\User\UserProvider

services:
  ginsberg_user:
    class: "%ginsberg_transportation.user.class%"
  user_provider:
    class: "%user_provider.class%"
    arguments:
      ["@ginsberg_person.person_repository", "@logger"]
  ginsberg_person.person_repository:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments:
      - Ginsberg\TransportationBundle\Entity\Person
```

My UserProvider.php class starts like this:

```
namespace Ginsberg\TransportationBundle\Security\User;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Ginsberg\TransportationBundle\Entity\Person;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
  private $personRepository;
  private $logger;

  public function __construct(\Ginsberg\TransportationBundle\Entity\PersonRepository $personRepository, \Monolog\Logger $logger) {
    $this->personRepository = $personRepository;
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }

    public function loadUserByUsername($uniqname)
    {
      $password = "admin";
      $salt = "";
      $roles = array();

      if (self::is_authenticated() && self::is_approved()) {
        if (self::is_superuser()) {
          $roles[] = 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN';
        } elseif (self::is_admin()) {
          $roles[] = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
        } elseif (self::is_eligible() && self::is_approved()) {
          $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        }

        return new User($uniqname, $password, $salt, $roles);
      }

      throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
      sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $uniqname));
    }
...
    public static function is_approved()
    {
      $uniqname = self::get_uniqname();
      $status = $this->personRepository->findStatusByUsername($username);

      return($status == 'approved') ? TRUE : FALSE;      
    }
```

I also tried using property injection too, but that didn't work either.

Should I just make my UserProvider class extend another appropriate class that would make use of a constructor? If so, any thoughts on what class would be fitting?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you integrate your services and custom user providers in your *security.yml* ?

Comment: factory_service and factory_method are deprecated. So, you should use `factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "getRepository"]` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the method `is_approved()` is `static`. You cannot use `$this` in a static context. You need to declare your method non-static.

Comment: Good grief. I can't believe I did that. Thanks.